# awesome wm crash on login

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I installed awesome wm the other day and accidentally changed `/etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua` instead of `~/.config/awesome/rc.lua` So I reinstalled to attempt to get a copy of the original file. I did `sudo apt-get remove --purge awesome*` to remove all files, I then saw that the changed rc.lua was still there, so I deleted that manually and reinstalled using apt-get again. Now, when I try to log in using awesome, it kicks me back to login screen.

I am on Debian Wheezy and my rc.lua located in ~/.config/awesome is at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/aVqEPw0R)

.xsession-errors after attempted login shows this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/gtGQVFta)

Comment: It seems to be due to this error: `/etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua:40: attempt to index global 'beautiful' (a nil value)`.

Comment: So what do I need to do to fix this issue? I have awesome and awesome-extra installed

Comment: Try replacing ``require("beautiful")`` with ``local beautiful = require("beautiful")`` in your ``rc.lua``. You may have to do the same for the *naughty* library.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. It still kicks me back to login.

Comment: Which awesome version did you install? Can you think of anything that could cause files from another version of awesome to be around?

Comment: 4.7.2, but do you think there would be a difference in the fact that I compiled from source after I installed it?

Comment: @Zachary Alfakir The [Debian package](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/awesome) in stable is a couple versions behind.
The config format changed since then due to the move from Lua 5.1 to 5.2, see [the sources](http://git.naquadah.org/?p=awesome.git;a=blob;f=awesomerc.lua.in;h=a67247a43fe292628d12cf8f497b24ffd87cf63d;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Does 'awesome -k' give you any output? It checks your config file for syntax errors

Comment: Here's an original config, you can replace your rc with this file http://pastie.org/10281652. Hovewer if you showed your config files I could tell you whats wrong

Answer (score -1):

I would try to manually delete the directories /etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua and ~/.config/awesome/rc.lua. Then reinstall awesome.

Comment: The problem seems really basic, there's no need for wiping whole system